# Get Last Inserted Message in ActiveMQ - Java

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am looking for an optimal way to browse/check the last message inserted in a particular queue.
So far I am thinking of `ActiveMQQueueBrowser`. See the code below:

```
ActiveMQQueueBrowser browser = (ActiveMQQueueBrowser) session.createBrowser(queue);
Enumeration e = browser.getEnumeration();
TextMessage message = null;
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    message = (TextMessage) e.nextElement();
}
```

But this code will need to traverse all the messages in queue, untill it gives last message.

plz suggest if there is any other way to do so.

Comment: What about use `.values()`to get an array of all the enum constants? then you can do `myArray.get(myArray.size())`

Comment: @canillas Enumeration interface is different that Enum, Enumeration is similar to iterator. Enumeration does not have constants/values it iterates on a datastructure.

Answer (score 0):

is JMX possible ??
see below example, you can order the messages as you want after loading them into a list.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.BrokerViewMBean;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.QueueViewMBean;

public class JMXGetDestinationInfos {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://host:1099/jmxrmi");
        Map<String, String[]> env = new HashMap<>();
        String[] creds = { "admin", "admin" };
        env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
        JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);
        MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

        ObjectName activeMq = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost");

        BrokerViewMBean mbean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, activeMq, BrokerViewMBean.class,
                true);
        for (ObjectName name : mbean.getQueues()) {
            if (("TEST".equals(name.getKeyProperty("destinationName")))) {
                QueueViewMBean queueMbean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, name,
                        QueueViewMBean.class, true);
                List<?> messages = queueMbean.browseMessages();
                System.out.println(messages.get(messages.size() -1));

                System.out.println(queueMbean.browseAsTable());
                System.out.println(queueMbean.browseMessages());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

another option if your counter is always available and connected is to use http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

> ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageDelivered.Queue Message delivered to the
>   broker.
>
> ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageDelivered.Topic Message delivered to the
>   broker.

Comment: This code _still_ has to "browse" the messages which will involve traversing all the messages in queue which is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to fetch the last message in the queue without traversing all the other messages with a browser (or something like a browser).

Keep in mind that a queue is not like a database table. You can't just pick out only the messages you want.